# How can I make logic judge of an empty tibble?

Tags: r, tidyverse, tibble

I want to decide whether a tibble is empty or not; I have the following code. what is the best way to do so?

```
> a<-tibble()
> is.na(a)
<0 x 0 matrix>
> is_null(a)
[1] FALSE
> sum(!is.na(a))
[1] 0
> sum(is.na(a))
[1] 0
> b<-tibble(1)
> sum(is.na(b))
[1] 0
> sum(!is.na(b))
[1] 1
> is.null(b)
[1] FALSE
> !sum(!is.na(b))
[1] FALSE
> !sum(!is.na(a))
[1] TRUE
```

Answer (score 2):

I'd go with

```
> nrow(a)+ncol(a)
[1] 0
```

Or maybe (to catch tibbles with multiple rows and no columns or multiple columns and no rows)

```
> nrow(a)*ncol(a)
[1] 0
```

Comment: Checking the rows is sufficient. A tibble with multiple columns but no rows is still empty.

Comment: Good point. I edited my answer

Comment: Hmm, that’s not what I meant. I meant simply `nrow(a) == 0L`. The number of columns is irrelevant for determining whether a tibble is empty, and in particular a tibble *cannot* have zero columns if it has at least one row (but, conversely, it *can* have multiple columns but zero rows, but it’s still empty then).

Comment: (I take that back, subsetting actually allows ending up with a tibble with > 0 rows and 0 columns. What the eff.)